# VS2008 PDB file size limit redux: LNK1201, too

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, pdb-files

What is the size limit on PDB files in VS2k8?  I am on a dev workstation with 3GB each of RAM and pagefile on a 32-bit PAE kernel, but the linker kicks out an LNK1201 error shortly after the PDB grows past 1GB.  Is MSPDBSRV simply running out of address space?

Comment: I've worked on some *very* large programs but never got close to a gigabyte.  Sure, the error message *tells* you that you are exceeding an internal limitation.  High time to split off code into DLLs.  Ought to help a great deal with the monster link times as well.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 (64-bit) on Windows 7 and encountering the same error.  After the linker quits with this error, the Windows Explorer "Properties" dialog for the .pdb file reports "Size on disk: 1.00 GB (1,073,741,824 bytes)".  Is this seriously still a hard limit on the size of the PDB file?  How can we get around this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308861/lnk1201-visual-c-2010-large-project-failing-to-generate-pdb