# Detect building with symbols in preprocessor on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, c-preprocessor, debug-symbols

Is there any way to detect when compilation is happening with debugging symbols enabled with the preprocessor? (when using cl.exe)

(Background: Our compile will fail due to toolchain .pdb size limitations, so I'd like to #error earlier rather than have the compile/link fail after a lengthy build.)

Comment: Why would your toolchain care about the size of an external PDB file? And isn't that a more serious problem that you should be seeking to fix? I mean, how are you going to effectively debug your app if you don't have symbols available?

Comment: The VS toolchain fails when the PDB is > 1G. Yes, it's a serious and complicated problem to fix; I was just hoping to diagnose earlier in a lengthy build.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't run into this limitation before. Surely it's time to split the code out into some DLLs, then? Especially since I don't think there is an answer to your question. And it might help you deal with the absurd link times you are surely experiencing. I also turned up this possible workaround: [LNK1201 Visual C++ 2010 Large project failing to generate PDB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16308861). That's supposed to give you 2 GB total for your PDB files, which should get you through until you make those DLLs.

Comment: Thanks again. That's what we were doing under VS2010 (I implemented that hack for Chromium in https://codereview.chromium.org/11968015/ that chrisha's generalized, which that SO post is based on!). But it causes mspdbsrv to be very flaky (crashes frequently) on VS2013, sadly. I filed connect bugs for these, of course, but ... not quick turnaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build the command line for cl.exe, if you decide to pass `/Zi` (or whatever option you're using for pdb generation), also pass `-D_SYMBOLS_GENERATED`.  Then, in the code, just use `#if defined(_SYMBOLS_GENERATED)`.

Comment: Just to update this for http://xkcd.com/979/, I confirm that with VS2013 Update 2 the PDB size limit is raised from 1G to 4G. Our largest is "only" 2.1G at the moment, so ... I deem this problem solved forever. "But what abou--". Zip it! FOR. EVER.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think of is:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #error "no debug builds, sorry"
#endif
```

It is possible to have _DEBUG defined but not be creating .pdbs, but somehow I doubt you guys are doing that.

The preprocessor reference is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4skk93w.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but yes, we do separate "debug" from "symbols".